# awk: using column variable as a pattern

Tags: awk

I have a table of similar values that are unfortunately formatted differently (out of my control), and I'd like to awk only those rows where $1 and $2 are completely different. My two main issues of concern are:

1) I have not had luck with

`awk '$1 !~ /$2/' filename`

even partially completing this task; it produces an empty set. I have a feeling it is how I am writing the /$2/ part, but cannot find a format that does not produce an empty set or an error.

2) The formatting differences are not the same across the board. Here is a sample of the input:

```
q12345      12345
Q012345     D66666
q12345      Q12345
Q012345     12345
q12345      23588
```

I'd like to only return the rows with obviously different values like so:

```
Q012345    D666666
q12345     23588
```

One ray of hope seems to be that each pair of columns has an identical sequence of numbers if the letters and sometimes preceding 0 are ignored. Any help would be appreciated. If it helps, this is in korn shell.

UPDATE: I see I made a common mistake for me of assuming everyone knows what I'm talking about for no good reason. By "obviously different," I mean that numbers in the values sans the preceding 0 are different. After typing this, I realize that the letters are effectively meaningless for the specific task I am performing on this data. So q12345 and 12345 are the same for my purposes, and 012345 and 12345 are the same, but 12345 and 78945 are not, nor is 12345 and 12346.

Now that I type this, is there just a simple way to only return the numbers in each column so that just the numbers can be compared? In this way, the preceding zeroes will be meaningless (012345=12345), and I'll get what I want. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: What means two things match? Same starting letter? Same numeric sequence? Or both/either?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time out to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). You need to add more details to your post, and more specifically, ask a clear and concise question.

Comment: I updated my question to answer your question Sobrique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the revised description, this seems to do the job (the sample data is in a file called `data` on my machine), though I concede there may be more compact ways of achieving the same result:

```
$ awk 'substr($1, match($1, /[0-9]+/)) +0 != substr($2, match($2, /[0-9]+/)) + 0 { print }' data
Q012345     D66666
q12345      23588
$
```

The `match` and `substr` functions are defined for POSIX [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).  The `match` function returns the offset of the start of the regex in the first argument, so it returns the index of the first digit in `$1` or `$2`.  The `substr` returns the string starting from that location.  The `+ 0` ensures that the values are treated numerically (so leading zeros are ignored) — without that, the `Q012345 12345` line was reported too.

Tested on a Mac (macOS Sierra 10.12.13, with native (BSD) `awk` and GNU `awk`).

---

> I think I'm running into a similar situation to another poster's answer below where I presumably have some weird/old implementation of Awk. The code kept returning an illegal statement error. This version of Awk does not have `match`…

This works with just the `sub` function, which applies a regex to a variable and replaces what matches with, in this case, an empty string, thus deleting the non-digits at the start of the field (or, if there are digits at the start, but non-digits later, it'll remove those; heaven help you if you have a field `1234-5678-99` because you'll end up comparing 12345678 with the other field).  There's also `gsub` which applies the search and replace repeatedly.

```
$ awk '{ v1 = $1; sub(/^[^0-9]*/, "", v1); v2 = $2; sub(/^[^0-9]*/, "", v2); if (v1 + 0 != v2 + 0) print }'  data
Q012345     D66666
q12345      23588
$
```

If you don't have `sub` or `gsub` either, then (a) please identify platform — o/s and version — and the version of Awk, and (b) please get and install GNU Awk so you don't have to futz around like this.  If that's a problem, provide a link to online documentation for the version of Awk you do have and most likely another solution is possible.

If you're on Solaris, try `nawk` (new Awk) instead of `oawk` (old Awk) — where `awk` may be a link to `oawk` or `nawk`.  If that's the issue, rejig the system to make `nawk` the default.

Comment: I think I'm running into a similar situation to another poster's answer below where I presumably have some weird/old implementation of awk. The code kept returning an illegal statement error.

This version of awk does not have match, so I tried index. I then isolated the problem to using regex in index, which is weird since index worked when I replaced regex with a number, and regex worked in other aspects of my code when using the ~ like operator.

Comment: You should probably try to identify the version of Awk that you have.  The match function is in POSIX Awk, but it must presumably be more recent than your version. I'll meditate on alternatives; they're messier but doable.

Comment: Well eff me. Apparently this system has nawk implemented, which has match(). Literally just had to add an 'n' to the beginning of your original code to make it work. Sorry for the hassle; if you couldn't tell, I'm pretty new to this system and awk in general. Thanks for the answers everyone. :)

Comment: If you're on Solaris you should use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk, not nawk. The former is much closer to POSIX compliance while nawk is very old and doesn't even support character classes. Of course you should really get/use GNU awk (gawk) for far superior functionality than either of those awks. That solution seems vastly over-complicated for what the OP is trying to do but maybe I just don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

if the pattern is contained in a variable, don't use the slashes -- you use slashes to contain a static regex. You want

```
awk 'tolower($1) !~ tolower($2)' filename
```

Using `tolower` to enable case insensitive matching. Or if you're using GNU awk:

```
gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 '$1 !~ $2' filename
```

Comment: if the columns are compared against each other perhaps making it symmetric is the better `$1 !~ $2 && $2 !~ $1`

Comment: Good ideas, but for some reason toupper/tolower is not working on my system (letter remains the same case for printing and comparison purposes) and '$1 !~ $2' produces an error.

Comment: what implementation/version of awk are you using? Does `!($1 ~ $2)` give an error?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does depend a bit on what you mean by 'completely different'. I mean, you could forward and backward substring match by:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ( $first, $second ) = split;
    print unless ($first =~ /$second/i or $second =~ /$first/i);
}

__DATA__
q12345      12345
Q012345     D66666
q12345      Q12345
Q012345     12345
q12345      23588
```

Which would give you:

```
Q012345     D66666
q12345      23588
```

This one-liner-ifies as:

```
perl -lane 'print unless ( $F[0] =~ /$F[1]/ or $F[1] =~ /$F[0]/ )'
```

Or you could do it based on 'Levenshtein distance':

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Levenshtein qw(distance);;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ( $first, $second ) = split;
    print unless distance ( $first, $second ) < 3;
}

__DATA__
q12345      12345
Q012345     D66666
q12345      Q12345
Q012345     12345
q12345      23588
```

Note - Q012345  -> 12345 is a Levenshtein distance of 2, so you could adjust the level of similarity.

Note - I know you've tagged `awk` and asked about `korn` shell. I've given `perl`, because it's *usually* available when either "korn" or "awk" are.

You can replace the `__DATA__` above, which is mostly useful for creating a self contained example by simply:

```
while ( <> ) { 
    my ( $first, $second ) = split;
    #etc .
}
```

`<>` is the magic file handle that works just like you would expect grep, sed or awk - reads stdin or files specified on command line so you can either:

```
cat somefile | script.pl
```

Or

```
script.pl somefile
```

And it will do the right thing in either case.

Comment: Thanks for the perl idea. I've never worked in perl, but did a few tests and it's easy enough to call the perl script from inside my korn shell script. Could you point me in the right direction to how to feed specific columns from a file into the  __DATA__ of the perl script?

Comment: Yes. Remove then data block entirely and use `while (<>) { ` instead. This will read from stdin or named files just like sed/awk/grep. I will edit with an example.

Comment: Note that while Perl is readily available, the Text::Levenshtein module is not installed by default (it is not a core module), so that solution may not work well unless you can install modules easily (CPAN or CPANPLUS, or …)

Comment: Yes, that's true. But 'cpan install Text::Levenschtein' is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but it seems like all you need is:

```
$ awk '{x=$0; gsub(/[^0-9 \t]/,"")} $1!=$2{print x}' file
Q012345     D66666
q12345      23588
```